# Apt error on ubuntu 18.04: Could not handshake: Error in the pull function

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, proxy, apt

I'm trying to install Jenkins on my machine by following the instructions at https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/.

However every time I try to run apt update, the Jenkins repository gets ignored, apt states the repo does not have a release file.

So I tried running `apt update --allow-insecure-repositories`, and I get the error below:

> Err:9 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Packages
>
> Could not handshake: Error in the pull function. [IP: 10.57.97.78 3128]

The command:

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

gives an OK response, so I assume that nothing went wrong here.

I'm sitting behind a corporate proxy, and the proxy settings are in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

`/etc/apt/sources.list` has the following lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe multiverse
deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/
```

Comment: Share your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I need that file to answer this question.

Comment: @E.N.D updated the same in the question.